# h2o H2OAutoEncoderEstimator

Tags: h2o

I was trying to detect outliers using the H2OAutoEncoderEstimator.
Basically I load 4 KPIs from a CSV file.
For each KPI I have 1 month of data.
The data in the CSV file has been manually created and are all the same for each KPI

The following picture shows the trend of the KPIs:
[image]

The first black vertical line (x=4000) indicates the end of the training data.
All the others light black vertical lines indicate the data that I use to detect the outliers every time.
As you can see data are very regular (I'v copied & pasted first 1000 rows 17 times).
This is what my code does:

1. Loads the data from a CSV file (1 row represents the value of all kpis in a specific timestamp)
2. Trains the model using the first 4000 timestamps
3. Starting from the 4001 timestamp, every 250 Timestamps it calls the function *model.anomaly* to detect the outliers in a specific window (250 timestamps)

**My questions are:**

- Is it normal that every time that I call the function model.anomaly the errors returned increases every time (from 0.1 to 1.8)?
- If I call again model.train, the training phase will be performed from scratch replacing the existing model or it will be updated with the new data provided?

This is my python code:

```
data = loadDataFromCsv()


nOfTimestampsForTraining = 4000
frTrain = h2o.H2OFrame(data[:nOfTimestampsForTraining])
colsName = frTrain.names

model = H2OAutoEncoderEstimator(activation="Tanh", 
                                hidden=[5,4,3], 
                                l1=1e-5, 
                                ignore_const_cols=False, 
                                autoencoder=True,
                                epochs=100)
# Init indexes
nOfTimestampsForWindows = 250
fromIndex = nOfTimestampsForWindows
toIndex = fromWindow + nOfTimestampsForWindows

# Perform the outlier detection every nOfTimestampsForWindows TimeStamps
while toIndex <= len(data) :
    frTest = h2o.H2OFrame(data[fromWindow:toWindow])
    error = model.anomaly(frTest)

    df = error.as_data_frame()
    print(df)
    print(df.describe())

    # Adjust indexes for the next window
    fromIndex = toIndex
    toIndex = fromIndex + nOfTimestampsForWindows
```